# How to bypass wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, angular, .htaccess

The public_html folder contains a wordpress site.  I have put a new Angular app in a subfolder called myapp.

so www.domain.com -> wordpress
and wwww.domain.com/myapp -> angular app

Now, if i refresh or try to access an url path (route) in angular, i get the 404 page of the wordpress site.

so the root (public_html) folder have an .htaccess like this :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In myapp folder (angular) i have this one :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myapp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Whatever i tries, it always end up as :  everything in myapp works ok, (refresh, direct url access etc) BUT the www.domain.com -> myapp!!!

Or

www.domain.com still -> wordpress
But
My angular app give me 404 on refresh and direct url access!

This is my .htaccess i consider should works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Condition to get in my angular app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myapp/.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /myapp/index.html [NC,L]

#Condition to go in wordpress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myapp/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!!  it worked!!!

Lesson learned!!! dont try to mix .htaccess of different folders!!

The wordpress .htaccess didnt need any changes.

The Angular one (subfolder) changed like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

So basically 2 things!!!

1. Removed the RewriteBase /myapp/
2. Removed the / in RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]

Hope this will help someone else ;-)